# How do I send a SNMP trap to multiple managers using snmp4j?

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

Need to forward the snmp trap to multiple managers.
Below is the snippet used to send trap to single target address and it is working as expected.

```
Address targetaddress = new UdpAddress(ConnectionPropertyUtil
    .getProperty("snmpAddress").toString()+ "/"+ConnectionPropertyUtil.getProperty("snmpPort").toString());

CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
target.setAddress(targetaddress);
Snmp snmp = new Snmp(new DefaultUdpTransportMapping());
snmp.send(trap, target, null, null);
```

Is there any way where I can set multiple targetAdresses and send trap at a single shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define one CommunityTarget for each manager.
If there is more than one, it probably should go in a `for` loop, fetching their addresses from a file or other source.